# Append a table with local storage key values. Can't work out how to append to my two column table with row headings, FirstNname, LastName

Tags: javascript

I am trying to append a table with new information stored in local storage.
I can get a list of the value keys no problem with the following code. However I cannot work out how to then loop through each key to get the associated value to append to my table consisting of two columns with row headings first name, last name.

```
for(var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
    console.log(localStorage.key(i));
}
```

Comment: Could you post the contents of `localstorage` and the code where to append values?

Answer (score 0):

try use `for ..in` . Example:

```
    for(var i  in localStorage){
         if (localStorage.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                    console.log(i,localStorage[i]);
                }
          }
```

Comment: Thanks very much for quick reply. It does exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Note that `for ... in` doesn't preserve the index order (if that's something important to you)!

Answer (score 0):

If index order is important for you, then use this in your existing loop (instead of `for ... in`):

```
localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i));
```

For example:

```
var cellValue;

for(var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
  cellValue = localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i));

  // Do something with the value
  console.log(cellValue);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, It should get me out of trouble.